# Reference error $ is not defined in local network access (jQuery)

Tags: php, jquery

I have a php project that I run it via wampserver inside my own computer and it works great. But the problem is, that when I want to access it from a local computer that is in this network, the website loads incomplete and when I track it via firebug it has this error :

```
Reference error $ is not defined
```

Error corresponds to a js file .

This is my php file that invokes js file :

```
<?php  
class ControllerModuleBanner extends Controller {
    public function index($setting) {
        static $module = 0;

        $this->load->model('design/banner');
        $this->load->model('tool/image');

        $this->document->addScript('catalog/view/javascript/jquery/flexslider/jquery.flexslider-min.js');

        $data['banners'] = array();

        $results = $this->model_design_banner->getBanner($setting['banner_id']);

        foreach ($results as $result) {
            if (is_file(DIR_IMAGE . $result['image'])) {
                $data['banners'][] = array(
                    'title' => $result['title'],
                    'link'  => $result['link'],
                    'image' => $this->model_tool_image->resize($result['image'], $setting['width'], $setting['height'])
                );
            }
        }

        $data['module'] = $module++;

        if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/module/banner.tpl')) {
            return $this->load->view($this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/module/banner.tpl', $data);
        } else {
            return $this->load->view('default/template/module/banner.tpl', $data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Something is calling jQuery but jQuery isn't loaded before it's called. Make sure to load jQuery before your application scripts.

Comment: It works in my own computer

Comment: Can we see the code you are using? Your answer to Amit suggests you are using a PHP framework, so please let us know what that is too. What is the HTML you are using to load jQuery where it does not work?

Comment: (I'm voting to put this on hold for now, but if you can improve it, ping me and I'll vote to unhold. Best of luck with it!).

Comment: I've edited my first post

Answer (score 0):

Either:

- You are not loading jquery or the path is incorrect
- You are using protocol-less url which will work in web servers but not on local server.
- You are using jquery plugins before loading jquery.

Comment: I called it via this command : $this->document->addScript('catalog/view/javascript/jquery/flexslider/jquery.flexslider-min.js');